# Best server side video processing library or software

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, video-processing

I need your suggestion on selecting the right command line tool 
that would allow me to process user uploaded videos.

By processing I mean:

- Convert to flv, mp4, ogg etc formats
- Modify quality, bitrate, framerate etc
- Control file size and other attributes
- Might need to process video in batch mode

This processing will be done though some scheduled process that would grab the file and then process. The tool must have command line utilities.

I only know the free FFMPEG library. 
Are there other (if costs money then fine) tools that allow me to do these?

What is used by youtube if you know it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) is pretty good library that has very good open source resouces.

I use it server-side in java(jax-rs) REST api where the actual ffmpeg is invoked in by this process:

```
@Path("/ffmpeg")
public class FfmpegResource {


    @GET
        @Produces("text/plain")

        public String getFfmpeg(@QueryParam("infil1") String infil1, 
                @QueryParam("infil2") String infil2, @QueryParam("otfil") String otfil,
                @QueryParam("t") String time) {         
        String outfil = "dummy.mp4";

          List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
            command.add("vendor/bin/pars_submit");

            command.add(infil1);     

            command.add(infil2);
            command.add(otfil);
            command.add(time);

System.out.println("Starting process " +command.toString());
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            Map<String, String> environ = builder.environment();
            Process process = null;
            try {
                process = builder.start();

            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  

                outfil=line;
            }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
            finally {
                  if (process != null) {
                    process.destroy();
                    process = null;    //           int exitVal = process.waitFor();
 //           System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
                  }                                 
                }                                           
            return outfil;                              
                }
}
```

calls to this script(pars_submit) that does the ffmpeg work:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
uri=$1
filnam="${uri##*/}"
uri2=$2
filnam2="${uri2##*/}"
otfil=$3
time=$4
curl -#LO  $uri
curl -#LO  $uri2
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i "$filnam" -i "$filnam2" -t "$time" -r 1/2 -pass 1 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 200k -bt 50k  -an -f mp4 -strict -2 -passlogfile mydummy /dev/null
# echo "ffmpegP1 Exit status" $?
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i "$filnam" -i "$filnam2" -t "$time" -r 1/2 -pass 2 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 200k -bt 50k  -f mp4 -strict -2 -passlogfile mydummy -ar 44100 "$otfil" 
# echo "ffmpegp2 Exit status" $?
# last test
json=$(curl  -X POST  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: 3KxPBTPSTe8f0iexGanSagCztLp6wSPzJkyMLAbR" -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: kVl5Z0CXmBSCoQRmE8XSLIDFuLGHMCIkLXXjkuI9"  -H "Content-Type: video/mp4"  --data-binary @"$otfil" https://api.parse.com/1/files/"$otfil")
# echo "parse POST Exit status" $?
echo $json
```